# 'An exception occurred during a WebClient request" while using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#

So, I have built an auto update program to my program.

The code that is running in here is:

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile("XXXX", checkingfolder.SelectedPath);
```

the XXX is my webserver that is running as a VPS server in verio, with the newest IIS and everything.

When the user clicks on the download button, it says:

```
'An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

The thing is, that I dont even know why - i am just doing try catch.

Anyone here have any idea why this happened?

Thanks for any help you will give me, you have no idea how much you are helping me here - thanks again !

Comment: Log the *details* of the exception. That should show what's going on.

Comment: I *very* much doubt that the details of the exception including "durning" a WebClient request. Are you sure you don't have code which is swallowing the WebClient exception and just logging that message without doing anything with the exception?

Comment: @Jon typo aside, I can repro something similar enough to be convincing

Comment: @MarcGravell: I suspect you're right - but by the *details* of the exception, I'd have expected the inner exception too. (That should always be checked...)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I can reproduce this if I specify, as *seems* to be the case in your example, a **folder** name rather than a **file** name the destination. Supply a **file** name instead.

As an aside; if I look at the `InnerException`, it tells me that the problem relates to the file path:

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.DownloadFile(
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033619/an-exception-occurred-durning-a-webclient-request-c-sharp-asp-net/8033687#8033687",
            @"j:\MyPath");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
Access to the path 'j:\MyPath' is denied.
```

If I change it to a **file**, it works fine:

```
client.DownloadFile(
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033619/an-exception-occurred-durning-a-webclient-request-c-sharp-asp-net/8033687#8033687",
    @"j:\MyPath\a.html");
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this error can occur when another class or process is accessing the file you've just downloaded

Answer (score 3):

it gives exception, if directory to path does not exist.

for example path is  **@"j:\Folder\SubFolder\123.pdf**
and **SubFolder** does not exist ,it will throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when I was trying to download a file, where the resulting downloaded file path would have been longer than some arbitrary limit

After changing the downloaded file's path name to be 250 characters long, the problem went away

Answer (score 1):

Beside other answers, beware that the same **WebException** might also occur if the client process does not have needed permission to create output file.

I would suggest you to take the following strategy:

1. Download file to a unique filename with **.tmp** (**.txt**) extensions Windows Temporary Folder to avoid write-permission and other permissions issues
2. Move temporary file to destination folder
3. Rename temporary file to destination filename

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

If Directory does not exist,this error message comes as
'An exception occurred during a WebClient request"
Because Web Client Does not find the Folder to store downloaded files.

Hope it Helps-:)