# Pulling files down from a web address using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue where I am trying to pull all the files down from a web link.  I need to pull all the files down and place them on a local directory on my computer.  This is what I have so far, and any help would be appreciated.

```
$storageDir = "C:\Proj_Vader"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$url = "http://Branches/Proj/Source/DB/"
$file = "$storageDir\*"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

Seems like it is working to the point of accessing the acutal web link, and then transfering the data down.  Getting "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" error message when trying to execute.  Also, I am basically trying to copy all of the files from the URL to a local folder.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. What works? What doesn't? Where specifically are you stuck? What is this "web link" - is it a page listing a bunch of files that you need to retrieve? What does it look like? Are you trying to parse it to find the links?

Comment: You will need to grab the directory content separately and loop through it. More details on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8033687/775544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the code is here, but this would be the framework for you to flesh out...

```
$SiteData = Invoke-WebRequest $url 

foreach ($weblink in $SiteData.links)
{
        $weblink.href
        #  create full local path and filename 
        $file = ''  # do your stuff here

        $clnt = new-object System.Net.WebClient  #  $clnt | gm
        $clnt.DownloadFile($weblink.href, $file)

}
```