# How to download CSV file automatically from a URL address?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to asp programming and I need help on downloading CSV file from a specific URL every hour.

Ideally, I would like to download a csv file automatically every hour(ex. 4:15 PM) to a specific folder on my hard drive. The website where I am downloading it from may not upload the desired file each day by that specific time (ex. 4:15 PM EST), so I would like my program to look every 15 minutes thereafter to see if the file is there and download it once it is. I also want to overwrite the file saved on my hard disk because the uploaded CSV data from the website have the same filename. So the CSV data on my hard disk must be the updated data.

I tried this code but got some exception:

```
Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wc.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ABC", "AJ77A")
wc.DownloadFile("http://samplewebsite.com/webclients/sample/SAMPLE.CSV", "C:\FOLDER")
```

The exception of above code is this:

> An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post more details about the exception?

Comment: this one sir..."An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
Access to the path 'C:\FOLDER' is denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must type a filename as the second parameter.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033619/an-exception-occurred-during-a-webclient-request-while-using-c-sharp-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set write permissions to the path you're specifying to IUSR user or IIS_IUSERS group take a look to this [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis)